# Mailchimp api not working with fetch and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mailchimp, fetch-api

I cannot get the fetch api to work with the mailchimp api in React. I'm also using webpack to run a devserver.

This is what I have:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let authenticationString = btoa('123:myapikey-us17');
    authenticationString = "Basic " + authenticationString;

    fetch('https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/fakelistid/segments', {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': authenticationString,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).then(function(e){
      console.log("fetch finished")
    }).catch(function(e){
      console.log("fetch error");
    })
  }
```

I've tested the exact same api request in Postman and that works fine.

When I try this in React I keep getting a 401 status code saying "Your request did not include an API key."

Comment: I really, really wouldn't do that from the front end. You're potentially exposing your Mailchimp API key to anyone who opens up their browser's dev tools. If you need to fetch data from a third-party API that requires authentication, you need to do so on the server side (and this obviously isn't server-side because `componentDidMount` doesn't get called during server-side rendering).

Comment: I understand that it's highly unsecure and I do plan on moving the code to a backend but what exactly is causing the issue I currently have?

Comment: I think you should change `credentials: 'same-origin'` to `credentials: 'include'`

Comment: To be honest you might not be using the same library to make the request on the server so any solution I give you may not be much use, but a 401 status basically means that you haven't provided valid authentication credentials, so something is clearly wrong with the `Authorization` header. I would try using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to see if you can replicate the error in that.